# How to get a information from a model in Django via it's user id in the url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to fetch the `Player` information that has a certain `user_id` directly in my url. I know I can get info by the `Player` id by simply passing a number, but how can I get the player based on its `user_id`? Is this possible?

`` fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/players/PASS_USER_ID_HERE_NOT_PLAYER_ID`) ``

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=False)
```

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: ForeignKey is one-to-many relationship, meaning that single User might have many Players. If so, then for given user_id how you pick one player out of many?

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the information based on one field of your model Class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you should use a `ForeignKey` field in your model. Perhaps you want a `OnetoOneField` if you want each instance of `MyUser` to be linked to just one instance of `Player`. Else, django will return a QuerySet instead of `Player` instances, even if the QuerySet contains just one instance of `Player`.

In case you do use a `OnetoOneField`, you could use
`players/<int:user_id>` as your url, and in your `View`, you could pass a `lookup_field = 'user_id'`.

Answer (score 0):

Set lookup_field in your view to "user__pk" (or "user__user_id" if primary key field of MyUser is named user_id) and queryset to Player.objects.all(). Also, your URL must contain user__pk kwarg.

Like this:

```
class PlayerDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = "user__pk"
    serializer_class = PlayerSerializer
    queryset = Player.objects.all()

path('api/players/<int:user__pk>/' , ...)
```